# Python to CURL using requests-save output to file

Tags: python, json, curl, pycurl

i want to convert this BASH code to python script:

```
curl -XN -u user:Pass -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='"Technology"+AND+summary~"Remove%20User*"+AND+issuetype="Task"+AND+status!="DONE"' | python -m json.tool > /var/lib/rundeck/1.json
```

So far i have this

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('jql', 'project="Technology" AND summary~"Remove User*" AND issuetype="Task" AND status!="DONE"'),
)

response = requests.get('https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/search', headers=headers, params=params, auth=('user', 'Pass'))

print response
```

as response i get `<Response [200]>`

How to print output of this command to JSON file (as in bash script) ?

with this code a get JSON file but not in JSON structure (as plain text):

```
with open('/var/lib/rundeck/1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(response.content)
```

Used this converter:

https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: Try to use 3rd library requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
response.raise_for_status() # throw on failure
with open('/var/lib/rundeck/1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(response.json()))
```

Comment: `outfile.write(response.json())
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: this one worked:`with open('/var/lib/rundeck/1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(response.content)` but content is not in JSON format

Comment: @Milister: I updated it to use `str()` to turn the JSON back into a string.  But when you say "content is not in JSON format" can you say what format it was in?

Comment: Instead of hundred lines, file contains only 2-3

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following

```
from json_tricks.np import dump

with open('response.json','w') as responseFile:
        dump({'Data': response },responseFile)
```

Comment: `TypeError: class "cookielib.DefaultCookiePolicy" does not have a __new__ method; perhaps it is an old-style class not derived from `object`; add `object` as a base class to encode it`  Python 2.7.5

Comment: when you `print response` do you get the json response or only the `200`

Comment: only `200` but when adding additional code (posted it in question) then getting plain text file

Comment: Pardon me I didn't get it. How can you only print `200` and right after the output code the json information is printed. `response` variable should already contain the json information when is printed. 
When you mean plain text file, do you mean that you see just one json line? If so, that is not a problem, it's just not prettified.

Comment: in print response i just get 200 yes, i see only one JSON line, but tested it and can parse it, so it works :), thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

In Python2

```
import requests
import json


url = '<URL>'
payload = open("data.json")
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

with open("output.json", "w") as outfile:
     json.dump(response.json(), outfile)
```